# Can't run Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, osx-yosemite

This is the output when I attempt to run Wireshark from the X11 command line. If I click on the .app icon it'll show up in the dock and then shut down immediately. This is being run on OS X Yosemite.

```
$  /Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS/Wireshark 
2014-10-24 19:28:46.231 defaults[20691:213803] 
The domain/default pair of (kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, AppleAquaColorVariant) does not exist
2014-10-24 19:28:46.240 defaults[20692:213809] 
The domain/default pair of (kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, AppleHighlightColor) does not exist
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libXext.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.0.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a specific programming problem. It might fit better at [apple.se].

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a specific programming problem.

Comment: Why is this downvoted when nobody moved this question to a more appropriate community? Obviously this has helped at least a few users.

Answer (score 20):

Wireshark expects X11 to be accessible via `/usr/X11`, when it's actually in `/opt/X11`. Installing or re-installing Quartz adds a symlink, upgrading to Yosemite removes it.

You can simply do:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/X11 /usr/X11
```

And that should fix the problem.

Comment: I actually see a syslink in `/usr/X11` and nothing in `/opt/X11`.

Comment: @Xeoncross, if you have nothing in `/opt/X11`, that probably means you don't have X11 (XQuartz) installed?

Answer (score 6):

In my case I had to uncheck in **X11 Preferences > Security Tab > Authenticate Connection**. Before that, all X11 Applications, like Wireshark or Dia appeared in the Dock, but didn't show any window. Unchecking **Authenticate connections** did the trick.

[image: X11 Preferences]

Comment: And what possible consequences result from your method?

Answer (score 0):

I too had the problem, wireshark app was opening and getting exited immediately in my Yosemite. I had the sym link and all in place. Now I did the below steps

```
1. Run X11 first
2. X11-->Applications-->Terminal
3. Put this  /Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS/Wireshark
```

This started wireshark.